# This formula gives $8^{-1}$ (mod $n$). Is there a deeper pattern lurking here?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Pick $n\equiv 1$ (mod $4$) which is not a multiple of $3$ and such that $n>5$. Consider the sum
$$S(n):=2\cdot\frac{n-1}2+3\cdot\frac{n-3}2+\ldots+m(m+2)+m+1,$$

where $m:=\frac{n-1}4$. For example, for $n=17$ we are considering
$$2\cdot 8+3\cdot 7+4\cdot 6+5.$$

Then we can show, by expanding $$S(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{m-2}(2+i)\left(\frac{n-1}2-i\right)+m+1$$

and applying the formulas for triangular and pyramidal numbers, that in fact
$$S(n)\equiv 8^{-1}(\text{mod } n),$$
as the numerator of the resulting fraction reduces to 1 (with a denominator of $8$).

(We cannot do the same for multiples of 3 because of the factor of 6 in the denominator of the pyramidal formula).

The simplicity of the final expression is a happy finding. I wonder:

1) Is there a neater explanation for it? Should we in fact expect the numerator to be 1?

2) More in general, can we pinpoint by some method other similar sums with particularly simple reductions?

For example, for $n\equiv 3$ (mod $4$) we get $S'(n)\equiv -11\cdot 2^{-5}$ (mod $n$) with $S'(n)$ the sums of pairs from $2\cdot\frac{n-1}2$ until possible without repetitions. Could we predict this, or choose to avoid this formula in behalf of another?

3) Is there some simple way of getting prime factors other than $2,3$ for the inverse of the final result, apart from adding more factors to the products (i.e., taking sums of products of $k$ numbers)?

Comment: Your $S(n)$ is unclear.  "Then we can show, by expanding $S(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{m-2}(2+k)\left(\frac{n-1}2-k\right)$" Supposing that $i=0$ should be $k=0$, we get $S(17)=2\cdot 8+3\cdot 7+4\cdot 6$ which contradicts that "For example, for $n=17$ we are considering $2\cdot 8+3\cdot 7+4\cdot 6+5.$"

Comment: @mathlove Thank you, I have corrected the two errors (I forgot to add the last term, $m+1$)

Comment: OK. But note that $$S(n)=2\cdot\frac{n-1}2+3\cdot\frac{n-3}2+\ldots+2\cdot\frac{n-1}2+(m-2)m +m+1$$ is *not* the same as $$S(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{m-2}(2+i)\left(\frac{n-1}2-i\right)+m+1$$(see when $i=m-3$ and $i=m-2$)

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question. But, for $n=25$ (which satisfies the conditions you gave), we obtain $S(n)=3514$. Also, $3514*8= 28112$, which is not equal to $1$ modulo $25$. In particular, $S(25)\not\equiv 8^{-1}\pmod{25}$

Comment: @mathlove Yes, I see that the first formula was also incorrect, I was too careless. We have the sum of products of two factors, the first one increasing from 2 to $m$, the second one decreasing from $\frac{n-1}2$ to $m+2$; finally we add the only number from $2$ to $m+2$ we have not used, which is $m+1$.

Comment: @FYY My first formula was badly written (see also my last comment addressed to mathlove). For 25 it should be $S(25)=12*2+11*3+10*4+9*5+8*6+7=197$, which indeed is $197\equiv 22\equiv 8^{-1}$ (mod $25$)

Comment: We can prove that $$8S(n)=\frac{(n-1)(n^2+7n-12)}{12}$$ and that $$8S(12k+1)\equiv 1\pmod{12k+1},\qquad 8S(12k+5)\equiv 1\pmod{12k+5}$$ though I'm not sure if what you want in 1) is the proof.

Comment: @mathlove That surely is interesting, and an improvement over my proof (how do you prove it?). What I'm seeking for is the "simplest" explanation on one hand, something which ideally would allow us to say "but of course this must be naturally so, as is easily seen with this simple argument"; on the other hand, for ideas which allow generalization to similar expressions. In some way I realize that I was also looking for a less algebraic and more number-theoretic "explanation": is this cancellation in the numerator easily understanable, like in Wilson's theorem, or more of a flicker?

Comment: Your claim is easy to prove by some calculations (which might be tedious), but I don't have any "less algebraic and more number-theoretic" explanations. So, it seems that I cannot be very helpful here.

Comment: @mathlove Well, perhaps you could make an answer providing a proof for your formula, since it seems simpler than my approach by triangular and pyramidal numbers.

Comment: I've added some steps for my previous comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer.

Using that
$$\sum_{i=0}^{N}1=N+1,\qquad \sum_{i=0}^{N}i=\frac{N(N+1)}{2},\qquad\sum_{i=0}^{N}i^2=\frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}$$
we have
$$\small\begin{align}8S(n)&=8\sum_{i=0}^{m-2}(2+i)\left(\frac{n-1}{2}-i\right)+8m+8\\\\&=-8\left(\sum_{i=0}^{m-2}i^2\right)+(4n-20)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{m-2}i\right)+(8n-8)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{m-2}1\right)+8m+8
\\\\&=-8\cdot \frac{(m-2)(m-1)(2m-3)}{6}+(4n-20)\cdot\frac{(m-2)(m-1)}{2}+(8n-8)\cdot (m-2+1)+8m+8
\\\\&=-8\cdot \frac{(m-2)(m-1)(2m-3)}{6}+(16m-16)\cdot\frac{(m-2)(m-1)}{2}+32m (m-1)+8m+8
\\\\&=\frac 43m(4m^2+9m-1)
\\\\&=\frac 43\cdot\frac{n-1}{4}\left(4\left(\frac{n-1}{4}\right)^2+9\cdot\frac{n-1}{4}+1\right)
\\\\&=\frac{1}{12}(n-1)(n^2+7n-12)
\end{align}$$

Now, integers such that
$$n\equiv 1\pmod 4\quad\text{and}\quad n\not\equiv 0\pmod 3\quad \text{and}\quad n\gt 5$$
can be written as
$$n=12k+1\quad\text{or}\quad n=12k+5$$
where $k$ is a positive integer, and we have

- $8S(12k+1)=(12k+1)(12k^2+8k-1)+1\equiv 1\pmod{12k+1}$
- $8S(12k+5)=(12k+5)(12k^2+16k+3)+1\equiv 1\pmod{12k+5}$